# JPA : Can I catch the Eclipselink drop-and-create event?

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

In persistence.xml I can declare the following :

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
```

Is it possible to catch this event and execute code ?

I am running on glassfish 3.1.

Comment: what do you mean by "execute code" ? You can load up data into the database using standard JPA 2.1 properties (rather than EclipseLink specific)

Comment: @Neil Yes the idea would be to populate the DB from an xml file. How do you mean ?

Comment: JPA 2.1 has standard named properties. _javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action_ should be set to "drop-and-create" and _javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source_ can be set to the name of a script file to load data. These are standard so should be in the docs for your JPA provider. See for example http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/emf.html#Standard_JPA_Properties

Comment: You're brilliant, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA 2.1 has standard named properties. `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` should be set to "drop-and-create" and `javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source` can be set to the name of a script file to load data. These are standard so should be in the docs for your JPA provider.